# Export from SQL Server to Excel and Email as Attachment through SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, ssis

I realize that this question spans many technologies, but I am only looking for high-level contributions here.

I am currently tasked with exporting from a SQL Server proc into Excel, and then email the Excel file as attachment through SQL Agent. The SQL Agent job must be run daily.

What I have tried:

- SQL -> Excel using xp_cmdshell & bcp. This is fine but then the excel output changes non-alpha text fields to numbers. (ie. phone numbers)
- SQL OpenRowset. I can't overcome the lack of the Jet 4.0 provider to use OpenRowset due to 64bit Win7 -- from what I understand.
- SSIS. After overcoming the dynamic file name predicament, I get stuck when my data types in from SQL to Excel didn't match up. (some Unicode to non Unicode issue)
- I can write the export process in .NET but then I do not know how to attach it to SQL Agent.

I guess my biggest question is, if you were going to address this yourself (as I am sure many of you must) which technology path should I take?

NOTE: I am almost certain I should not install Office on the Server

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it's going to Excel, can we assume it's richly formatted or would a CSV suffice? Must SQL Agent be the mechanism for sending the email or can it simply be used to schedule the Extract-To-Excel-And-Email-Process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd definitely use SSIS. I'd have a Data Flow task reading the stored procedure output and writing to the Excel file, then a Send Mail task to handle the emailing of the resulting spreadsheet. (I've cleaned up Unicode vs. non-Unicode confusion in the past using Derived Column transformations in my Data Flows.)

SQL Agent could be used to kick off the SSIS package, although I haven't used it.

Comment: Thanks man. This is the route I have decided to take. It seems SSIS is a tool that can handle all phases of the requirement. I'll give the Derived Column a whirl.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have SSIS on the server available to you, you can email attached CSV files using `sp_send_dbmail` with the right combination of parameters:

```
declare @tab char(1) = CHAR(9)
exec  msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='dbProfile', @recipients='email@domain.com', @subject=@emailsubject, @attach_query_result_as_file=1,
    @query = @sqlQuery, @query_attachment_filename='filename.csv',@query_result_separator=@tab,@query_result_no_padding=1
```

The full list of parameters and what they do is here: [sp_send_dbmail (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

This SQL can then easily be added to a stored procedure and run as a Job.

Comment: I know this is an old reply, but the @tab char(1) = CHAR(9) helped me out today, all my results were appearing in a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write the export in .net, then in setting up the step for your job, one of the steps options is "Operating system (CmdExec)" which would allow you to point it to your .net application.